# How to make installer exe ( framework + application)

Tags: installation

I am Game Developer, my game is ready and I have one problem, I need your help. My game use camera steam and it need

```
    Intel Redistributable Libraries 2011 for C++
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributables
    .NET Framework 4.0
```

I want to make one installer. I must at first check if Windows have this 4 , if not it must install. After this 4 install it must install my game. I look 2-3 software but there I can't install framework or Visual C++ 2010 Redistributables. Can somebody help, write link , idea or any useful information.

I use [this](http://martin-klappacher.com/tutorial-windows-installer-for-your-unity-game/) software but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) tool. I think what you need would be to add your game installation files in Files and Folder page and then add the redistributables and the .Net framework as [prerequisites](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites) in [Prerequisites](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites.html) page. Advanced Installer already have predefined prerequisites for Visual C++ 2010 and 2012 Redistributable and for .NET 4, so for this you would need to only select them in the predefined list from Prerequisites page.

Comment: Thanks for answer , I will try and write comment about

Answer (score 0):

you can costomize this code and convert it from batch file to exe.

```
@echo off
color f0
:: overwrite your program name after the '=' ::
set ProgramNameHere=ProgramNameHere
goto start
:start
cd/
cd users
cd %username%
cd desktop
md %ProgramNameHere%
:: overwrite your file path on the 'DATA' ::
:: overwrite your file name on the 'file1', 'file2'...
:: overwritw your file name after the 'extracting'.
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file1.txt
echo extracting file 1
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file2.txt
echo extracting file 2
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file3.txt
echo extracting file 3
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file4.txt
echo extracting file 4
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file5.txt
echo extracting file 5
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file6.txt
echo extracting file 6
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file7.txt
echo extracting file 7
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file8.txt
echo extracting file 8
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file9.txt
echo extracting file 9
ping localhost>nul
echo DATA>>C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\%programNameHere%\file10.txt
echo extracting file 10
ping localhost>nul
goto exit

:exit
exit
```

Alon